# Where did the comments go on this question?

Tags: discussion

Just had a [recent question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/215050/102) where a bit of back and forth in the comments. Par for the course in isolating what is going on.

I get that comments should be considered *transient/ephemeral* and any important details need to go into the actual question or answer.

Yet sometime between yesterday and this morning **all** the comments have disappeared from both the question and answer.

**Where did all the comments go on this question and answer?**

I certainly didn't delete mine.

From the tab I had left open overnight:

[image]

Loaded in new tab this morning:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah when comment chains get very long we moderators sometimes clean them up. Often I will migrate them into chat, but if it looks like the issue is completely resolved sometimes I just remove them altogether. I can restore these particular comments if you feel they still add value, or migrate them to chat. It just seemed like the problem was solved.

For posterity here's what was written:

> I just observed the logs on Apex debug console while making the request again from my failed queue, and I see this: 01:55:23:077 DUPLICATE_DETECTION_MATCH_INVOCATION_DETAILS EntityType:Lead|ActionTaken:Allow_[Alert,Report]|DuplicateRecordIds:00Q1r00001CojKl. The Duplicate ID that Salesforce cries about by no way has the same email that is being inserted. Two different emails entirely. I am confused.
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> Please see my updated screenshot on OP.
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> Thanks Daniel for your help. This is not true. The Lead ID that Salesforce claims is being duplicated has a different email and No Contact at all..
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> And yes my that Rule is indeed active :Lead with Duplicate contacts. Should I disable it. But it doesn't seem to do with contacts. The error logs purely refer to Lead Duplication(?)
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> Disabling that rule would need to be a call for whoever admin's that org. I'd assume it is on for a reason. All I can say for sure is that the debug log is indicating that log as the reason the insert is rejected. I suspect that if you search harder you might find the record it identified as the duplicate. Or even just try manually inserting the same lead record directly in the Salesforce UI.
>   – Daniel Ballinger
>
> I just created the Lead with the email in concern and it works absolutely fine from the UI dashboard without any errors whatsoever..Hmm..now then..what could be going wrong :(
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> Not just the email. It needs to be every field that is being populated. Especially F/L Name, Email, Phone, Address, Title.
>   – Daniel Ballinger
>
> Alright, it appears that if the phone number is the same, it throws up..that does seem weird to me..shouldn't be happening in a real world but still..how do I disable that
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> Oh sorry, it's the last name. That is very strange. Many people can have same last names. It shouldn't ever throw up..How do I disable this uniqueness check on LastName entirely?
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> You either: 1) complete turn off the rule (not recommended without admin approval), 2) Use the DuplicateRuleHeader header on a SOAP request, or 3) manually make your own version of the REST API that allows you to specify the DuplicateRuleHeader on the DML in Apex.
>   – Daniel Ballinger
>
> Nevermind, I am just being paranoid. The test user entered the same information and it wouldn't ever happen in real world that FN, LN and PHONE are all same so I'll let it pass. Thanks Daniel :)
>   – Ali Gajani
>
> So to clarify for whoever is reading this answer. The duplicate check of FN AND LN AND PHONE was being triggered hence preventing the lead creation. This doesn't happen ever in the real world so a non-issue.
>   – Ali Gajani

Comment: Fair enough. I'm mostly surprised there is zero notification about it happening. I'll scan through what I can still see in my old tab to see if anything should be merged into the question or answer.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Added the comments here so you can just copy-paste as needed.

Comment: All cleaned up now. Thanks. I should take my own advice that comments should be considered ephemeral.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Cheers. Hopefully not too sharp a reminder!

Comment: I'm all good with the comments being deleted to keep things clean. However, I do think Stack Exchange should provide a short grace period before completely removing them. I.e. you get a notification that they will be gone in X hours and you need to merge anything you think is important into the Q or A.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yeah it's easier for us as mods since we can just view them even after deletion. That's one reason I typically prefer migration to chat. Then you have as long as you want to recover. I'll keep that in mind.